# nextjs: Error in mobile devices while fetching data on client side using swr

Tags: next.js, swr

I am trying to implement client side data fetching using [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) in `nextjs`. I am able to display the data fetched using the `useSWR` hook fine in my desktop browser. I then serve the app on localhost from my desktop and try and test it on my mobile browser over wi-fi (both devices on the same network). The client fetched data is not displayed. Instead the `<Error />` component is returned.

What could be possible reason(s) for this? I haven't really seen people bringing up a similar issue on the internet

in `useSWRFetch.js`

```
...
const fetcher = (...args) => axios.get(...args).then(res => res.data)

export const useSWRFetch = (url) => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)

  return { data, error }
}
```

in `ClientFetchedComponent.js`

```
...
export default function ClientFetchedComponent() {
  const { data, error } = useSWRFetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/category/featured`)

  if (error) return <Error />
  
  return <div>
    { !data ? 
      <Loading /> :
      data.results.map(item => {
        return <div key={item.id}>
          ...
          ...
        </div>
      })
    }
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**localhost:8000** is located on the PC, mobile has its own localhost as well that has no apps running.

If you want to use another device with same WIFI replace **localhost:8000** with **IPv4 Address.** **ex(192.168.1.4:8000)**

Find it on **cmd > ipconfig**

Comment: Oh yes, completely forgot to think about that logic. I know what you mean. Thanks.