# CORS issue: Testing a MERN app on mobile using local IP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, mern

I am trying to test out my MERN app with Next.js on my mobile using my local IP address. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try perform any action on the app that requires a connection to my express server, axios throws an error. I have narrowed this down to a CORS issue, but cannot work out why it is blocking a connection through my local IP? I have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` set btw. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you're running any time of add blockers etc on your phone I'd suggest turning them off. 

Are you sure the url you're using on your mobile device is formatted correctly?

Comment: Add code snippets, we can't figure out what is wrong without looking at the code

Comment: Nevermind, I still had my API calls set to localhost from a client not running on the same localhost as the API. Changed the API calls to the IPv4 address instead and hey presto.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123274/nextjs-error-in-mobile-devices-while-fetching-data-on-client-side-using-swr/69123877#69123877

Answer (score 1):

I still had my API calls set to localhost from a client not running on the same localhost as the API. Changed the API calls to the IPv4 address instead and hey presto.