# Unable to load data on React App running locally (guess NOT CORS issue)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I have this

- web app frontend (port: 3000) on React, running locally on Mac OS;
- backend (port :5000) running on express, access mongodb locally and allowed incoming traffic from all by CORS config.

When testing on same machine using Chrome, app runs fine and get all the data thru the api call using axios to the server and pulling the data from mongodb.

Website loads all data fine and able to make POST request to database successfully too.

Then I test the web app on mobile device, and work good the frontend, using the default address for same network (http://10.0.0.227:3000/), but when I try to get data from backend, no data loads. I wonder why?

Neither can't make POST request. Not even getting any errors nor a 404 or app crashing at all.

Interesting... on same mobile device, I hit the endpoint (http://10.0.0.227:5000/api/data) and it returns a JSON file and I can see the data requested on JSON format; so I guess based on this is not CORS related issues, since I'm getting response from the server with the data requested.

PS: I'm a junior developer, haven't found any article related to this issue, besides CORS allowed.

I have tried changing the CORS config to allow all incoming traffic, and successfully it gets the data back when making a GET request straight to the server from mobile device.

.env file:

```properties
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL= http://10.0.0.227:5000
```

FrontEnd:

```js
export async function loader() {
  try {
    console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data`);
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data`,
    );

    console.log("Fetched data:", response.data);

    return response.data; // Return the fetched data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error fetching data:", error);
    return 0; // Or handle the error as needed
  }
}
```

Backend:

```js
// Use the CORS middleware
const whitelist = ["http://10.0.0.227:3000"];

// Use the cors middleware to enable CORS for whitelist routes
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true); // Allow the request
    } else {
      console.log("Not allowed by CORS");
      // callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS")); // Deny the request
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
};

// Use CORS middleware
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get("/api/data", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const elevators = await Elevator.find(); // Fetch all data records
    res.json(elevators);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching data" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, "10.0.0.227", () => {
  const date = new Date();
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port} as of ${date}`);
});
```

Comment: What URL is your frontend app using to communicate with the server? Sounds like you've got it set to `http://localhost:5000` which won't work over your LAN. React apps run in the browser of the device and `localhost` refers to the device itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nextjs: Error in mobile devices while fetching data on client side using swr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123274/nextjs-error-in-mobile-devices-while-fetching-data-on-client-side-using-swr)

Comment: I tried this: backend disabled CORS at all; frontend updated the .env file to access the server via this REACT_APP_SERVER_URL= http://10.0.0.227:5000. Data is loading on client side from browser within same machine hosting front and back end; when connected from other device data not loading at all from react app. But when I hit this endpoint (http://10.0.0.227:5000/api/data) from other device, server returns data successfully on a JSON format.

Comment: Your CORS options could be greatly simplified to `cors({ origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://10.0.0.227:3000'] })`. If you're not using cookies, don't use `credentials: true`

Comment: Are you restarting the frontend dev server after making changes to the `.env` file? What debugging are you doing on the mobile clients? Depending on your browser and OS, you should be able to hook up some sort of remote debugger. For simple debugging you could always change those `console.log()` calls to `alert()`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and kindness, I was able to solve that with your help after couple weeks trying to find online solution I decided to post it and done.  Gonna simplify the CORS and try the alert() for mobile devices when debugging.

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: I had to correct in the React app the  URL address for the server, replacing the "http://localhost:5000" for  "10.0.0.227:5000"  and restart the front and back end to apply new changes. Now data is loading from all devices connected to the network. Thanks so much!